# ¿Como utilizar los operadores ternario para un return?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, operador-ternario

He estado aprendiendo los operadores ternario y tengo un inconveniente, tengo una variable, la cual si está llena debe imprimir lo que está allí, pero si no entonces que me imprima el resultado normal de una consulta.

Como puedo pasar el código de abajo a operador ternario.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if (MSJ != string.Empty)
{
    return new JsonResult(MSJ);
}
else
{
    return new JsonResult(DataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El **operador ternario** **?:** evalúa una **expresión booleana** y devuelve el resultado de una de las dos expresiones, dependiendo si esta es **true** o **false**.

En tu caso prueba con esto:

```
var resultado = (msg != string.Empty) ? new JsonResult(MSJ) : new JsonResult(DataTable); 

return resultado;
```

Aquí se evalúa la expresión:

```
(msg != string.Empty)
```

De ser **true**, el valor de resultado será:

```
new JsonResult(MSJ)
```

De ser **false**, el valor de resultado será:

```
new JsonResult(DataTable)
```

Por último se hace:

```
return resultado;
```

retornando de esta forma el valor guardado en la **variable resultado**.

Comment: Gracias @Japv, de hecho ya lo había logrado me quedo de esta manera ""return (MSJ != string.Empty) ? new JsonResult(MSJ) : new JsonResult(DataTable);""

Comment: Muy bien, genial!!!

Answer (score 1):

Es posible usar string.[IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-7.0) para determinar si un string es nulo o está vacío (como es evidente por el nombre de la función)

Luego en este caso el operador ternario se puede usar de 2 maneras:

1. Repitiendo el JsonResult

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(MSJ) ? new JsonResult(DataTable) : new JsonResult(MSJ);
```

2. Todo dentro del JsonResult

```
return new JsonResult(string.IsNullOrEmpty(MSJ) ? DataTable : MSJ);
```

El operador ternario evalúa lo de la izquierda,

- Si es `true` coloca lo del centro y
- Si es `false` coloca lo de la derecha.

`condicion ? si_es_verdador : si_es_falso`

Comment: Hay otra función parecida que puede interesar: `IsNullOrWhitespace`.

Comment: @Mateo Buena esa, no lo había usado nunca porque pensaba que no validaba el Empty (no lo pone en el nombre de la función), pero ahora que lo busqué https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0 si lo hace!!! Gracias por el dato